# Mysql query, allowing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Data( id, url ). One of the api in my project returns me the list of ids ( there could be duplicate ids in this list). For the sake of this question lets assume this list as ( 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)

I am trying to find the urls associated with these ids.

My first and naive attempt was to use IN clause:

```
SELECT url from Data where id in ( 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4);
```

This returns me four rows. i.e. urls for id 1,2,3 and 4.

What I want is six rows, each one for specified id ( duplicate rows need to be retained )

I understood that IN clause is not helpful in this situation. Could anyone please point me to right direction?

I could fire a query for individual id by iterating the list but its a last resort for me.

**UPDATE: Adding more details about table**

```
mysql> desc Data;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| url   | varchar(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Data;
+----+-------+
| id | url   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | a.com |
|  2 | b.com |
|  3 | c.com |
|  4 | d.com |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select url from Data where id in(1,1,2,3,4,4);
+-------+
| url   |
+-------+
| a.com |
| b.com |
| c.com |
| d.com |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I want is:

```
+-------+
| url   |
+-------+
| a.com |
| a.com |
| b.com |
| c.com |
| d.com |
| d.com |
+-------+
```

Comment: It could be useful, if you post the structure of that table.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Your `IN` list is redundant, yes, but there's no reason your query wouldn't return all 6 URLs with those ids. Also, if it's not unique, you shouldn't use `id` as your field name; that's confusing.

Comment: @EdCottrell Please see the updated questions. I hope that will clarify some of the doubts. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but

```
select url
  from Data
    inner join

( SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as id UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as id
) as list_table ) as table2

  on (Data.id = table2.id);
```

I found pretty much no way to `select` values from a list or `join` a table to a list, but you could check out this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072688/outer-join-using-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

this works very good

```
   SELECT url 
   from table1
   where id in ( 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc06c/2)

to drop the unique on id

```
   alter table Data drop index PRI;
```

to drop primary key

```
 ALTER TABLE Data DROP INDEX `PRIMARY`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my case id is primary key, its unique.

Comment: if you are going to store duplicates and select duplicates so why you are making unique on it? wanna remove the unique ?

Comment: please see the updated section. I don't think I could alter any table in my case. Its already populated. This data is going to be exported to excel sheet for frequency count and other purposes.

Comment: you will just drop the index primary you will loose anything.