# SQL Check to see if a value is present in a table

Tags: sql

I have a list of po_numbers that I need to see and note if they are NOT present in the ORDERS table.

Example:
870043334, 871280502, 871414230 etc.

I found a way to check each one separately..

```
if exists (select top 1 * from orders o where o.po_number IS NOT NULL and po_number in ('870043334')) select '' else select '870043334 DNE';
if exists (select top 1 * from orders o where o.po_number IS NOT NULL and po_number in ('871280502')) select '' else select '871280502 DNE';
if exists (select top 1 * from orders o where o.po_number IS NOT NULL and po_number in ('871414230')) select '' else select '871414230 DNE';
```

Is there a more eloquent way of just returning results where they DO NOT EXIST?

thank you!!

Comment: You can use an anti-join - but your `po_number` values need to be in a table already, so how/where is your list of `po_number` represented? Are they already in another table of their own - or if not, does your RDBMS support `@tableVariables` or `#temporaryTables`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OUTER JOIN using IN list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072688/outer-join-using-in-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to show these in a set, when they don't already exist in another set, we need a **projection** of the values into their own place. So start by putting them into dynamic table, whether via UNION, string_split(), table-value constructor, temp table or whatever.

I'll wrap this in a CTE so it comes out the same regardless:

```
WITH PO_NUMs As (
   select po_num 
   from (VALUES 
        ('870043334'),
        ('871280502'),
        ('871414230') ) p(po_num)
)
```

Then we can use the CTE with any of an exclusion join, NOT EXISTS, NOT IN(), etc:

```
WITH PO_NUMs As (
   select po_num 
   from (VALUES 
        ('870043334'),
        ('871280502'),
        ('871414230') ) p(po_num)
)
SELECT po_num
FROM PO_NUMS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from orders o where o.po_number = p.po_num)
```

Note this uses SQL Server syntax. Most other DBs also support table-value constructors, but sometimes the syntax is slightly different.